# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor

I am trying to learn Python. This is a really simple code. All I am trying to do here is to call a class's constructor, initialize some variables there and print that variable, but it is giving me an error, `missing 1 required positional argument`.

```
class DHT:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data['one'] = '1'
        self.data['two'] = '2'
        self.data['three'] = '3'
    def showData(self):
        print(self.data)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DHT().showData()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're receiving this error because you did not pass a `data` variable to the `DHT` constructor.

[aIKid's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19929739) and [Alexander's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19929837) answers are nice but won't work because you still have to initialize `self.data` in the class constructor like this:

```
class DHT:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data if data is not None else {}
        self.data['one'] = '1'
        self.data['two'] = '2'
        self.data['three'] = '3'

    def showData(self):
        print(self.data)
```

And then calling the method `showData` like this:

```
DHT().showData()
```

Or like this:

```
DHT({'six':6,'seven':'7'}).showData()
```

or like this:

```
# Build the class first
dht = DHT({'six':6,'seven':'7'})
# The call whatever method you want (In our case only 1 method available)
dht.showData()
```

Comment: Note that this solution has the following potential problem: `d1 = DHT(); d2 = DHT(); d1.data['four'] = '4'; d2.showData()` shows the entry with 4. In other words, subsequent constructor invocations that don't specify `data` get the same dictionary. In order to combat that, you often see `data=None` specified on the `def` line, followed by a first statement of the procedure that checks if `data` is `None` and if so replacing it with a fresh dictionary.

Comment: What's wrong in calling the constructors in this way?

Comment: An explicit if-else block to see if the `data` is `None` avoids issues with the alternative `self.data = data or {}` statement as the latter assigns an empty dictionary anytime a falsy object other than `None` is passed to the constructor.  For example, `False`, `0`, `""`, `[]`, `()`, `{}`, objects that specify `__nonzero__()` all evaluate to `False`, so using `self.data = data or {}` and passing such falsy objects will still create an empty dictionary. This may be the desired effect, however, keeping things explicit tends to make debugging easier so the if-else block is generally preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Your constructor is expecting one parameter (data). You're not passing it in the call. I guess you wanted to initialise a field in the object. That would look like this:

```
class DHT:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.data['one'] = '1'
        self.data['two'] = '2'
        self.data['three'] = '3'
    def showData(self):
        print(self.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DHT().showData()
```

Or even just:

```
class DHT:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
    def showData(self):
        print(self.data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. I am sorry for asking such stupid questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should possibly make `data` a keyword parameter with a default value of empty dictionary:

```
class DHT:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        data = data if data is not None else {}
        self.data['one'] = '1'
        self.data['two'] = '2'
        self.data['three'] = '3'
    def showData(self):
        print(self.data)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    DHT().showData()
```

Comment: Don't use a [mutable default argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)! Instead use `None` as the default then create the dict inside the function, like in [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19930369/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass some data into it. An empty dictionary, for example.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DHT('a').showData()
```

However, in your example a parameter is not even needed. You can declare it by just:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Maybe you mean to set it from the data?

```
class DHT:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data['one'] = data['one']
        self.data['two'] = data['two']
        self.data['three'] = data['three']
    def showData(self):
        print(self.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DHT({'one':2, 'two':4, 'three':5}).showData()
```

`showData` will print the data you just entered.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. I am sorry for asking such stupid questions.

Comment: No problem at all! If people can learn something from me, i'm already a happy bunny.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with, you

```
def __init__(self, data):
```

when you create object from DHT class you should pass parameter
the data should be dict type, like

```
data={'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
dhtObj=DHT(data)
```

But in your code youshould to change is

```
data={'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
if __name__ == '__main__': DHT(data).showData()
```

Or

```
if __name__ == '__main__': DHT({'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}).showData()
```

Answer (score 0):

If error is like

```
    Author=models.ForeignKey(User, related_names='blog_posts') 
TypeError:__init__()  missing 1 required positional argument:'on_delete'
```

Then the solution will be like, you have to add one argument

```
Author=models.ForeignKey(User, related_names='blog_posts', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```