# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' in remote server CentOS7.2

Tags: python, django

In my Mac I use PyCharm run my Django project very well.

But in the remote server I use the same commands to run my project:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 8001
```

The there comes the issue:

```
File "/var/www/html/Qiyun02//user_admin_productmanage_cloudserver/models.py", line 3, in <module>
        from xxx.qiyun_admin_productconfig_cloudserver.models import (
      File "/var/www/html/Qiyun02/qiyun_admin_productconfig_cloudserver/models.py", line 109, in <module>
        class Disk(models.Model):
      File "/var/www/html/Qiyun02/qiyun_admin_productconfig_cloudserver/models.py", line 110, in Disk
        diskEssenceType = models.ForeignKey(to=DiskEssenceType, related_name='disks')  #  "SAS", "SSD" and so on 
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

I know the `on_delete` error means. but I mean, in my Mac why there do not shows the error? whether this is related to django version?

My local Mac Django version is `1.11.2`.

The remote server CentOS7.2 version is `python-django-1.8.14-1.el7.noarch`

---

**EDIT**

Please, I know the `on_delete` error in there, I mean, in my Mac, there is no the reminds, why I copy to the CentOS7.2 remote server there comes this issue?  whether this is caused by django version?

---

**EDIT -2**

I upgrade the remote server django version to 1.11.2 too. but still have the same error.

---

**EDIT -3**

From the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> A many-to-one relationship. Requires two positional arguments: the class to which the model is related and the on_delete option. (on_delete isn’t actually required, but not providing it gives a deprecation warning. It will be required in Django 2.0.)

You know, my django version is 1.11.2 now in my CentOS7.2 remote server, why there have the issue there?

---

**EDIT -4**

I don't have a virtual environment.

I use bellow command:

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

get the same issue.

---

**EDIT -5**

In the end, I find my python3 use django 2.0. this is the issue.

```
python3 -m django --version
2.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929626/init-missing-1-required-positional-argument)

Comment: @Nepho See my EDIT, friends.

Comment: Can you post the code of your `__init__` method?

Comment: you have to use same django version anyway. a requirements file should be kept in project folder to track the right versions. Also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: see my edit-2, I upgrade success, but still have the same issue.

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment ? as per the doc, the error is for django 2.0 only. Please check your version using shell. python manage.py shell.  >> import django >> django.VERSION

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal See my EIDT-4, I don't have a virtual environment.

Comment: @Nepho What do you mean my friend, my django project do not have a `__init__` method, I don't know what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the doc, the error you are seeing will happen only for Django 2.0. Please check your Django version using shell

```
python manage.py shell
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
```

Also consider using a virtual environment. That is how a project should be set up.

Comment: @fanhualuojin154873 which version did you see using above method ?

Comment: See my EDIT-4, I use `python3 manage.py shell` will get the same error.  I am trying to use the venv now.

Comment: are you not even able see the shell ?

Comment: I have find my issue, my python3 use the django2.0, this is the issue, thank you.